# Memcached and lots of tcpip resets (as shown by netstat AND tcpdump) - Any ideas?

Tags: php, memcached, pecl, tcpdump, netstat

We use pecl's memcached (note the D, there are 2, memcache AND memcached) extension to connect to a cluster of memcached 1.4.13 boxes.

We have noticed a LARGE number of tcpip resets occuring:

```
[root@box ~]# netstat -s | grep unexpected
2078913548 connections reset due to unexpected data

[root@box ~]# tcpdump -n -v 'tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-rst) != 0' -nn
13:30:45.786577 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
LANSUBNET.1.19093 > LANSUBNET.4.999: Flags [R], cksum 0xfad9 (correct), seq 1996582451, win 0, length 0
13:30:45.786697 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
LANSUBNET.1.11540 > LANSUBNET.100.999: Flags [R], cksum 0x904c (correct), seq 2003170685, win 0, length 0
13:30:45.793199 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
LANSUBNET.1.55125 > LANSUBNET.3.999: Flags [R], cksum 0x42c3 (correct), seq 1998297456, win 0, length 0
13:30:45.793389 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
LANSUBNET.1.19112 > LANSUBNET.4.999: Flags [R], cksum 0xa2b5 (correct), seq 1993131641, win 0, length 0
13:30:45.793547 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
LANSUBNET.1.11564 > LANSUBNET.100.999: Flags [R], cksum 0x447c (correct), seq 2003255604, win 0, length 0
13:30:45.817874 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
LANSUBNET.1.55135 > LANSUBNET.3.999: Flags [R], cksum 0x841c (correct), seq 1995200572, win 0, length 0
13:30:45.818549 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
LANSUBNET.1.55141 > LANSUBNET.3.999: Flags [R], cksum 0x385d (correct), seq 1997841357, win 0, length 0
```

Memcached is bound on port 999 on all of our memcached boxes.

Are we diagnosing this incorrectly?

What could be causing this?

What we know for sure:

A) This is not related to the mecached pecl extension (note the d, there are 2 extensions... memcache AND memcached). We tried switching to the other, memcache extension and same issue occured.

B) This is in fact 100% caused by the memcache connections. We disabled our php -> memcached sessions, and the connections reset due to unexpected data in netstat stoped growing, instantly.

C) We have this issue occuring on 2 boxes, so I dont think its a server-specific issue. When I say 2 boxes, I mean 2 different servers, making OUTBOUND connections to our memcached cluster. They both sit on the same LAN.

Note: For security we changed our LAN subnet above to 'LANSUBNET'... This was done just prior to posting the message here ;)

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

---

**More Data:**

```
[root@box ~]# netstat -s | grep unexpected ; sleep 1 ; netstat -s | grep unexpected ;
2089258664 connections reset due to unexpected data
2089258858 connections reset due to unexpected data
```

So it would appear, durring a 'not so busy' time, the resets occur at about a 200 / sec rate. Ouch!

**Also, very much worth mentioning:**

We have executed the following:

```
tcpdump -nn -v 'tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-rst) != 0' and tcp port not 999
```

Thus filtering port 999 (where our memcached daemons sit on)... And the tcp resets slow to a tiny trickle... Few a minute, which I assume is acceptable on a fairly busy service.

Comment: may be you use binary protocol in your memcached client?

Comment: doubled checked, we are NOT using the binary protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have found a complete solution to this issue.

It is caused by the memcached pecl extensions "Memcached::OPT_BUFFER_WRITES" constant being set to true.

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution.

i doubt that anyone from twitter will ever read this, but if you are, thank you kindly:

twitter has recently (feb 2012 i believe) open sourced their memcached proxy.

https://dev.twitter.com/blog/twemproxy

in essence all this is is a ip:port OR socket based proxy for the memcached protocol.

you can bind it to a ip:port or socket. we chose the socket route.

so what we are left with is a locally hosted socket that we can access our pool of memcached servers from.

pecl extension memcached 2.0.0b1+ supports socket based connections.

so the step by step is now as follows:

php -> memcached 2.0.2 pecl extension -[LOCALLY HOSTED SOCKET]-> twitters awesome memcached proxy -[TRULY PERSISTENT CONNECTIONS]-> pool of memcached servers

the tcp resets have stopped.

---

**worth mentioning:**

we initally tried binding the twitter memcached proxy 127.0.0.1... even when we had pecl memcached communicate with the twitter proxy we were seeing the tcp resets.... strange!

i suppose this is not a 'fix' per say... but it solved the issue on our end.

enjoy!

Comment: While this solution would be ideal... it would appear that after an hour or so, pecl memcached starts having issues connecting to the twitter memcached proxy. Unsure weather its the pecl extension or the memcached proxy. But we are back at step one :(